# i don't understand this error = UnboundLocalError: local variable 'overWrite' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, file

if you could help me find out why this error is occurring it would be so helpful
and i am learning code slowly as a beginner so try not to judge me on this :)

```
import os
overWrite = ""


def filecheck():

    garry = ("i love this leason")

    filename1 = input("please enter a name : ")
    filename = filename1 + ".txt"

    dave = os.path.isfile(filename)

    if dave == False:
        print("you can have this name")
    else:
        overWrite = input(" do you want to overwrite this file : ")

    if overWrite == "yes":
        with open(filename)as f:
            f.write = (garry)

    else:
        filecheck()

filecheck()


please enter a name : ggggggg
you can have this name
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/computer science/dictionary test.py", line 26, in <module>
    filecheck()
  File "F:/computer science/dictionary test.py", line 19, in filecheck
    if overWrite == "yes":
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'overWrite' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you reference the variable `overwrite` in this line

```
if overWrite == "yes":
```

before it's necessarily given a value in the function. Python looks in the function's scope first, so you'd either need to tell it that when it sees `overwrite` it should look at the global variable `overwrite`, or you'd need to refactor your code. You can declare a variable as global within a function using the `global` keyword like this:

```
def filecheck():
    global overwrite
    garry = ("i love this leason")

    filename1 = input("please enter a name : ")
    filename = filename1 + ".txt"
    ...
```

[Here's the link](https://docs.python.org/3.3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python) to a bit about local vs global variables in the python docs.